# `findMany` where `id` ends with elements of an array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, prisma

I have an array of strings that are end part of document IDs

```js
const arr = ['ace', 'acb', 'acc', 'aca'];
const documents = [
  { id: 'xxxxxxxace' },
  { id: 'xxxxxxxacb' },
  { id: 'xxxxxxxacc' },
  { id: 'xxxxxxxaca' }
];
```

I need a query that would return all documents whose IDs ends with either of `arr` elements.

The only way I could do this is by iterating over `arr` and calling `findFirst` with `endsWith` for each array element.

Are there better ways?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```js
await prisma.documents.findMany({
  where: {
    OR: ['ace', 'acb', 'acc', 'aca'].map(element => ({
      id: {
        endsWith: element
      }
    }))
  }
});
```

I'm using Postgres, don't know if Prisma working the same on MongoDB but hope it help!

Answer (score 1):

Use `$indexOfCP` to check whether the suffix is located in the id. Apply `$map` for the array-wise oepration. Finally use `$anyElementTrue` to return the doc for matching any one of the cases.

```js
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    "$anyElementTrue": {
      "$map": {
        // your input array
        "input": [
          "ace",
          "acb",
          "acc",
          "aca"
        ],
        "as": "suffix",
        "in": {
          $ne: [
            -1,
            {
              "$indexOfCP": [
                "$id",
                "$$suffix"
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SYMijD4L58f)

Comment: He's using Prisma ORM, not Mongodb query

Comment: @HoàngHuyKhánh I don't think OP restricted his considerations to ORM only(at least not indicated obviously inside the question). I guess I may leave the MongoDB native query approach as one of the alternatives here.

Comment: This question contains `prisma` tag and OP also mentioned `findFirst` and `endsWith` which are `prisma` features. So I think native query is not an option here.

Comment: Thanks for the input but as @HoàngHuyKhánh said I'm using Prisma ORM. I could do this query with `aggregateRaw` but then prisma middleware wouldn't work. I was looking for a Prisma `findMany` solution. But there might be none so if I don't get a better answer I'll mark yours as a solution